# How to update user in the following structure

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Assuming my user is visiting places in the world, and the database looks like the following, what's the best practice to delete the user from the old place, and have him at the new place (so that this unique user can only be at single place at once)?

At first user is at `location A`:

```
database
    |
   places
      |___location A
      |        |___user1: "exact coordinates"
      |
      |___location B
               |___user2: "exact coordinates"
```

And this is how I want it to look like after moving `user1` to `location B`:

```
   database
        |
       places
          |___location B
                   |___user1: "exact coordinates"
                   |___user2: "exact coordinates"
```

How to move `user1` to `location B` while removing him from `location A`?
I am having hard time finding the correct syntax to simply delete the (uniquely identified) `user1` from his old place to his new place.

Comment: How about using a transaction to execute both CRUD operations sort of "together"? http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2731932&seqNum=2

Comment: But this is firebase database, or I am completely off? (Sorry I am a beginner)

Comment: Use a separate branch for users and places.  `users->user_1->{location, coords}`.  Perhaps the location is list of nearby userids `locations->location->{user_id : timestamp}`.  Throw an [`onWrite`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) trigger to remove the userid from the old location.

Comment: James, yes this should be a list of nearby userids, how did you know? :D. Do you have a place where I can see how to do that efficiently?

Comment: @JamesPoag, as a beginner, I can't find the relation between the `onWrite` in the link to the `onWrite` in Java code for android. How would I use `onWrite` inside my project in Android Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using your current database structure, in order to change the location of a user, you perform 3 operations:

1. Read the current location of your user:

   ```
   database -> places -> location A -> user1
   ```
2. Copy current location to the new location:

   ```
   database -> places -> location B -> user1
   ```
3. Remove the old location:

   ```
   database -> places -> location A
   ```

This can be solved by using a single update operation. In this case you should consider change your database structure a little bit like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- users
        |
        --- uid
             |
             --- lat: 48.856151
             |
             --- long: 2.298115
```

In order to update the location of the user, you should only update this two properties like in the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child(uid);
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("lat", 41.890362);
map.put("long", 12.492263);
uidRef.updateChildren(map);
```

Comment: when you use the `updateChildren(map)` does it automatically remove the old record from its old place in the database?

Comment: In this case, there is no old place and new place. There is a single place where you create a single update operation. With other words, you update current locations cooredinates with the new onces. That's it!

Comment: Oh true, just noticed that. But in this case, What is the strategy to find near by userIds by the lat and long? Could you please add a code for that? How to traverse in the tree for only nearby users when the database is structured like in your code? I don't know where to start! Because if there are many users it's gonna be inifite search. At first you check all users that are nearby according to lat, then if lat is correct you need to match long as well..

Comment: This is really a bit too broad to reasonably be able to answer in single comment here. Your initial question was `How to update user in the following structure` So hope I was able to provide you the best solution. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: If you think that my answer helped you for what you have asked first, please consider accepting it. I'd appreciate it. Thanks!